# Proof about the greatest integer function and the negative greatest integer function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be the function defined by $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor -x\rfloor$. Prove that $f$ has a limit at every integer $n$ but that the value of the limit is not $f(n)$.

Comment: What is $f(x)$ when $x$ is an integer? And what is $f(x)$ if $x$ is not an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $n$ is an integer, and $n<x<n+1$. Then $-n-1=<x<-n$.

- What are $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\lfloor -x\rfloor$ in terms of $n$?
- What is $f(x)$ in terms of $n$?
- What is $f(n)$?